# More regex tweaking advice required

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, expression

I'm getting through adding delimiters to a large references file thanks to help from SO. Almost there now. I have a regex which I received from an SO member which allowed me to add the "|" between the author and year. I know need to add "|" between the article and publication. The rule I cam up with is that I want to add the "|" after the last period(dot) that precedes the ":" in the publication name. I tried editing my positive look ahead for this but it does not seem to work. I would appreciate your input on this as always. Thanks in advance.

Actually I probably don't need even to specify the after 3 "|" rule. The main thing would be to match to the last period that precedes the ":". Would that be correct. Even so my regex does not seem to be working.

```
^((?:[^|]+\|){3}.*?\.)(?=\:)

122| Ryan, T.N. |2002. |Some article name here. Publication name 2: 101-105.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay 2 problems:

- You forgot that there is stuff between the period and the colon for the lookahead! :)
- You did not have a greedy match before the period, so it was matching the *first* period instead of the last

Try:

```
'^((?:[^|]+\|){3}.*\.)(?=[^:]*?\:)'
```

See the difference? (Removed a `?`, added a `[^:]*`)

Comment: tried this but its selecting the whole reference instead of stopping at the dot after "Some article here". Thanks though.

Comment: @jiraiya... It totally works in python, i tested it.  Try adding that question mark back and keeping the [^:]* maybe?  Or... time to use python hint hint : )

Comment: can't seem to get this working. you don't by any chance use the gskinner regex site do you. I'm testing it there but its not working. I appreciate the help thanks. This is what I have so far and it seems to be working but if brackets occur in the text it breaks. ^(?:[^|]+\|){3}(.*?)[^(?:Co)]\.(?=[^:]*?\:)